# i'm trying to work with xml linq xdocument in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to write a windows phone 7 app which reads from an xml using xdocument but i'm having a few problems.

If I do this:

```
Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(e.Result)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xml.ToString)
```

Or this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xml.Elements.Value.ToString)
```

then the xml data is output to the immidiate window as a string proving that the data exists but if i do this:

```
Dim products = From product In xml.Descendants("product") _
                    Select title = product.Element("title").Value

For Each product In products
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Title" & product.title)
Next
```

I get nothing for product.title and I also get nothing when I do stuff like this:

```
Dim count As Integer = xml.Descendants("count").Value
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

xml looks something like this:

```
<productslist>
  <count>2</count>
  <products>
    <product>
        <productId>1</productId>
        <title>test item 1 </title>
        <price>4.99</price>
        <category>
            <categoryId>1</categoryId>
            <categoryName>cat 1</categoryName>
        </category>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productId>2</productId>
        <title>test item 2</title>
        <price>10.99</price>
        <category>
            <categoryId>2</categoryId>
            <categoryName>cat 2</categoryName>
        </category>
    </product>
 </productslist>
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you're doing wrong when we don't know what the document looks like. Could you edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ statement is not projecting into an anonymous type with a property of `Title`. You're getting an `IEnumerable<string>` back directly.

Try this instead:

```
Dim products = From product In xml.Descendants("product") _
               Select product.Element("title").Value

For Each product In products
     Debug.WriteLine("Title: " & product)
Next
```

That said, the variable `products` is better named `titles`. If you want to project into an anonymous type you need to use `With New { .Prop1 = data, .Prop2 = other }`. A dot must be prefixed to each property name. Here's an example:

```
Dim products = From product In xml.Descendants("product") _
               Select New With { .Title = product.Element("title").Value }

For Each product In products
     Debug.WriteLine("Title: " & product.Title)
Next
```

For your example it doesn't seem that an anonymous type is needed. If you have multiple properties to project into then it becomes worthwhile.

**EDIT:** in response to your comment, a namespace might be attached to your XML. If so, you would need to reference it to reference any element.

If your XML has a namespace it should have an `xmlns` specified, such as:

```
<productslist xmlns="http://domain.com/namespace">
```

You would then have to modify your code to get the namespace and concatenate it with your elements as follows:

```
Dim ns = xml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

Dim products = From product In xml.Descendants(ns + "product") _
               Select product.Element(ns + "title").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get nothing. I checked products.Count and it returns 0 so the for each statement doesn't even fire

Comment: @JasperS that's odd. Can you set a break point and inspect `xml.Descendants("product")` to make sure those nodes are returned? Any chance your XML is using a namespace and doesn't exactly appear the way you showed it above? Namespaces need to be prefixed to element names.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by namespace in xml, I've not worked with xml much. What do you mean by prefixed to element names?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know VB But in C# this code will do-

```
var query = doc.Descendants("product").Select(x => new {Title= x.Element("title").Value});

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Title);

            }
```

Also the xml you posted is missing `</products>`. node (end tag), I hope it's just a copy paste mistake.